# beamer: how to hide/uncover pstricks object?

Tags: beamer, pstricks

I have a `\psBigArrow[fillstyle=solid,
fillcolor=blue!30,doublesep=2mm,linecolor=blue](240,92)(240,-62)` and would like that it will not appear all the time on the frame but only at some stage. I tried to use

```
\uncover<2->{
\psBigArrow[fillstyle=solid,
fillcolor=blue!30,doublesep=2mm,linecolor=blue](240,92)(240,-62)
}
```

but it does not work. 
How to solve it, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 1):

no problem here (run with xelatex):

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage{pst-arrow}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\only<1>{foo}

\uncover<2-3>{
    \psBigArrow[fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=blue!30,doublesep=2mm,linecolor=blue](0,0)(2,-2)
}   

\only<3>{bar}
\only<4>{baz}
\end{frame}

\end{document
```

Comment: You might want to mention that you changed the coordinates, which is why it worked, not the compiler.

Comment: I never said that it has something to do with the compiler!

Comment: I've tried this example and still I can see hiding\uncovering of the text elements (foo, bar, baz) but the arrow was on the slides 1-4 and did not diasappear.

Comment: I replaced \uncover with \only and it worked. Thank you for your help